# Qt C++ ffmpeg cannot find library

Tags: c++, qt, ffmpeg

I use Qt 5.0.2 with Mingw 4.7 on windows.

I'm working on a c++ program and i'm trying to get the duration of video files. I found [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/). Now i tried to compile a simple program but I think it fails with the libraries. I've tried to include both the shared and dev but they both will fail. ( [Zeranoe FFmpeg builds](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/))

This is my pro file:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += C:\programming\ffmpeg-20130606-git--win32-shared\bin

LIBS += -LC:\programming\ffmpeg-20130606-git--win32-shared\bin -lavcodec-55.dll -     lavformat-55.dll -lavutil-52.dll
```

i get errors like:

":-1: error: cannot find -lavcodec-55.dll"

":-1: error: cannot find -lavformat-55.dll"

I've also tried:

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:\programming\ffmpeg-20130606-git--win32-dev\include
INCLUDEPATH += C:\programming\ffmpeg-20130606-git--win32-dev\lib

LIBS += -LC:\programming\ffmpeg-20130606-git--win32-dev\lib -lavcodec -lavformat -lavutil

LIBS += -LC:\programming\ffmpeg-20130606-git--win32-dev\lib -llibavcodec.dll.a -llibavformat.dll.a -llibavutil.dll.a
```

Here it gives a error "During startup program exited with code 0x0000135'

I even tried to include each library individually. But no results..

This is my main file:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
extern "C" {
  #include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>    // required headers
  #include <libavformat/avformat.h>
}
int main(int argc, char**argv) {
   av_register_all();             // offending library call
   return 0;
}
```

A program simple as this will have 2 outcomes:

1. the program runs but crashes if i call 'av_register_all()'
2. It just tells me he cannot find the libraries.

Can someone tell me what it is i'm doing wrong? Or even give me a hint? I can't really find a lot of good documentation on this one.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure, but you may want to check out http://www.dependencywalker.com/ - you might not have a required dll in your path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure PRO-file as shown below:

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:\programming\ffmpeg-20130606-git--win32-dev\include

LIBS += -LC:\programming\ffmpeg-20130606-git--win32-dev\lib
LIBS += -lavcodec -lavformat -lavutil
```

Then, build the project, copy the all dll libraries from `C:\programming\ffmpeg-20130606-git--win32-shared\bin` to exe output path and run application.

UPD

Maybe you need to copy some of the following libraries from `Qt\5.0.2\mingw47_32\bin\`:

```
libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll
libstdc++-6.dll
libwinpthread-1.dll
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It works! Now i'm trying to get the duration. It works with MP4 files but not with AVI, FLV, WMV... Do you know where I went wrong?

I using avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, filename, NULL, NULL); and
 pFormatCtx->duration;